# How to dynamically create a form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, label

I have the following code
I am trying to dynamically create radio button with and without labels in them. I am unable to put the text in radio button when I create radio button, here is the code without labels
This is what expect

```
<input type="radio" name="Alex" value="Alex"/>Alex
```

```
$('<input>').attr({
   type:'radio',
   name:'name',
   value: "Alex",
   text:"Alex"
}).insertAfter("#divid"));
```

Now for having labels,

```
<label><input type="radio" name="Alex" value="Alex"/>Alex<label>
```

```
//create a label tag
var label = $('<label>', { text:"Alex"});
//append input tag to label
$(label).append($('<input>').attr({
    type:'radio',
    name:"Alex",
    value:"Alex"
}).insertAfter("#divid"));
```

Both of the above does not produce any error on console but it does not produce the right HTML tag I am interested in. Also is there a way to directly add label to radio as I create them dynamically. I mean I dont want to create a label tag separetely and append to it the radio button. Many Thanks for your help

Comment: It's not clear... `1.` what you have (initially); `2.` what you want to achieve; `3.` which one of the two (Both I suppose?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Dynamically create `label` and `radio`

[jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/biwoke/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
var $input = $('<input />', {
  type : "radio",
  name : "name",
  value : "alex"
});

$("<label />", {
  insertAfter: "#somediv", // (or use appendTo: to insert into it)
  append: [$input, "Alex"] // include our $input and also some text description
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="somediv">DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `var label = $('<label>').attr({ text:"Alex"});` with `var label = $('<label>').text("Alex");`

Also - you have few syntax errors in your code, I don't see what's so hard to copy+paste properly.

Comment: Xbrowser: `$('<label />')`

Comment: @Tomer-its not copy+paste. its a part of large code. I have to trim it down and modify some parameters to give attention to what is really needed

Answer (score 0):

I like [Roko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973787/4794), except that it's vulnerable to HTML injection if you're building the radio button labels from user content.

Here, I use the `.text()` method to make sure that the text is properly escaped.

```js
var $target = $('#target'),
    records = [{ id: 1, name: "Alex" },
               { id: 2, name: "Test that HTML <em>is not</em> injected" }];
$target.append('<h3>With Labels</h3>');
for (var i=0; i < records.length; i++) {
  $target.append($('<label>').text(records[i].name)
                 .prepend($('<input type="radio" name="mychoice">',
                            { value: records[i].id })));
}
$target.append('<h3>Without Labels</h3>');
for (var i=0; i < records.length; i++) {
  $target.append($('<span>').text(records[i].name)
                 .prepend($('<input type="radio" name="mychoice">',
                            { value: records[i].id })));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```